# What does plate mean in "we're running you in two plates"?

Tags: british-english, academia

I find the following line in Tom Stoppard’s play *The Invention of Love.* Mark Pattison, Rector of Lincoln College, Oxford, is speaking to entering students in the 1860s:

> . . . if you have come up to Oxford with the idea of getting knowledge, you must give that up at once. We have bought you, and we’re running you in two plates, Mods and the Finals.

I can find no definition for *plate* in the OED (subscription online version) that seems to fit this case.

Comment: OED: *plate* — 7. orig. and chiefly *Horse Racing.* A silver or gold trophy given to the winner of a race or other sporting contest; (hence) a contest, esp. a horse race, in which such a trophy is awarded.

Comment: @PeterShor I think that is right, and indeed had just made up my mind to pursue a horse-racing angle of inquiry. Care to make that an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mods and the Finals are exams that you are given at Oxford. A *plate* is a horse race or other sporting contest.  So the headmaster is (presumably jokingly) comparing Oxford's exams to a sporting event.

From the OED:

> *plate* — 7. orig. and chiefly *Horse Racing.* A silver or gold trophy given to the winner of a race or other sporting contest; (hence) a contest, esp. a horse race, in which such a trophy is awarded.